# Como calcular a velocidade da conexão de internet de um usuário?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estou tentando calcular a velocidade da conexão em MB de um usuário que acesso meu site. Porém não consegui achar muita coisa na internet além de programas prontos e sites que já fazem isso. A única coisa que consegui fazer foi calcular quanto tempo em milissegundos a página demora para carregar:

```
$(window).load(function () {
       var endTime = (new Date()).getTime();
       var millisecondsLoading = endTime - startTime;
       console.log(millisecondsLoading);
       // Put millisecondsLoading in a hidden form field
       // or Ajax it back to the server or whatever.
   });
```

Porém não sei como usar isso para calcular a velocidade de conexão em MB de um usuário!

Comment: `tamanho da pagina(em mb)/tempo de carregamento(s)`. A operação basica é essa, só não posso te garantir que é tão simples assim chegar a essa velocidade.

Comment: Ou o que vejo muitos sites fazerem é enviar um arquivo ao cache e calcular quanto tempo ele foi baixado pelo usuario por completo. O cálculo é o mesmo, só muda o procedimento, ao inves de sua pagina inteira, um arquivo a parte.

Comment: Mas com essa formula seria um pouco complicado pq toda vez que ouver alteração na página eu terei de recalcular o tamanho dela! :/

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer conforme o comentário do @diegofm, porém, veja que essa medida nunca dará um valor certo, pelos seguintes motivos:

- A conexão pode oscilar;
- A rota até o seu site pode variar de acordo com cada provedor de internet
- Se o usuário estiver com 10 abas do Youtube, por exemplo, carregando, o tempo será diferente.

É por isso que a maioria dos sites de medição pedem para o usuário fechar todos os programas que possam estar utilizando a internet.

Mas sim ainda quiser, como eu disse, a solução do @diegofm é até simples de ser implementada. Salve um cache de 1Kb por exemplo e calcule o tempo